# Why casting to object when comparing to null?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, comparison, null

While browsing the MSDN documentations on Equals overrides, one point grabbed my attention.

On the examples of [this specific page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx), some null checks are made, and the objects are casted to the System.Object type when doing the comparison :

```
public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
{
    // If parameter is null return false.
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
    TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
    if ((System.Object)p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
}
```

Is there a specific reason to use this cast, or is it just some "useless" code forgotten in this example ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible for a type to overload the == operator.  The cast to object ensures that the original definition is used.

Answer (score 15):

As others said, the type might override the == operator. Therefore, casting to `Object`is equivalent to `if (Object.ReferenceEquals(p, null)) { ... }`.

Comment: +1 Using ReferenceEquals is clearer to me than the cast to object

Comment: +1 The intent is more clearly shown by using ReferenceEquals.

Answer (score 7):

I believe casting to System.Object would get you around any operator overloading that TwoDPoint might have.

Answer (score 1):

It likely exists to avoid confusion with an overloaded == operator.  Imagine if the cast did not exist and the == operator was overloaded.  Now the `p == null` line would potentially bind to the operator ==.  Many implementations of operator == simply defer to the overridden `Equals` method.  This could easily cause a stack overflow situation

```
public static bool operator==(TwoDPoint left, TwoDPoint right) {
  return left.Equals(right);
}

public override bool Equals(System.Object obj) {
    ...
    TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
    if ( p == null ) {  // Stack overflow!!!
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

By casting to `Object` the author ensures a simple reference check for `null` will occur (which is what is intended).

Answer (score 0):

This might have been part of a larger sample where the == operator was overloaded. In that case, using obj == null could have resulted in StackOverflow if TwoDPoint.Equals(object) was invoked as part of the == definition.